# How to change the unit price in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, module, odoo, odoo-9, price

When I enter the price for my products in odoo, I would like to display them in EUR. But I still have them in Arabic :

My product price : 180 م.د

The desired result :

180 EUR.

Any help will be appreciated.

These images example can help :

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ah5DCQ19IxysgQQNmxsulmbvEiDP

https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ah5DCQ19IxysgQNi9BKZQ4dGIZ00

Comment: what's your default currency in `Settings -> Configuration -> Accounting`?

Comment: the default currency is EUR but it doesn't change anything

Comment: You should be more specific, for example where the currency is displayed

Comment: It's really hard to help, if we don't know where to look. Are you speaking of invoices? Maybe sales order?

Comment: Can you open the links I have added and look at the screenshot inside! so I'm new to Odoo and i think the settings are missing something! thanks for your reaction

Answer (score 0):

You can change it by setting a default company currency:

1) Go to Settings > Companies > Companies

2) Choose Configuration tab ,change currency to `EUR`.

Comment: The currency is EUR, but I don't have the same path, i can't find Companies in Settings! Am i missing something?

Comment: Use `Edit company data` on the top left corner.This will change currency for future use.

Comment: @K.ossama have you enabled technical settings and multi-company for your current user?

Comment: Yes I did but I still have the same problem! can you check the links above to look at the settings! thank you again

Comment: @K.ossama Check my edit (tested).I hope it will be useful.